# Unable to combine Auth and Resource servers into a single project

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am playing around with https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server examples and realised that I have to first start the auth server first before resource server because the resource server was doing a GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/.well-known/openid-configuration on startup. Does this mean i won't be able to combine both authorisation and resource servers into a single spring boot app?